# Is it possible to have my closed app run code in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Let's say that my app in iOS is closed. Would it be possible to set it up so that it runs a piece of its code after a certain period of time?

Comment: I don't think it's such a bad question. Downvoters and closers, please  distinguish better between bad questions and simple (noob) questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can have your app schedule [push notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), but you can't schedule it to run specific code unless it's running.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I asked, is because find my friends seems to do something similar, as it can give your location even when the app itself is not running, maybe I misunderstand how that application works.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you can also do that. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10 And there are a few other things you can do with the iOS4 multitasking apis. Trying searching around and you'll find some things.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you can not. At the most, your application will keep running in the background for 11 minutes, if you request the extra time (check the documentation for beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler on the UIApplication class). There are some things you can do: Schedule a local notification, which the user can use to launch the app, or use push notifications to remind the user of something he needs to know.

Answer (score 0):

iOS allows background processing for the following reasons:
- location dependent functionality
- background audio playback
- voip

You can find out more from Apple's multitasking documentation